# Setting multiple possible initial states in useState hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

The aim is to set the initial state:

- if the `StateColumn` is visible/applicable (true)
- and it should be `accepted` or `waiting_for_review` or `rejected` (or `nothing` if the StateColumn is not shown), depending on this order if they exist

This is what I did:

```
  const [selectedStuffState, setSelectedStuffState] = useState( showStateColumn? ('accepted' || 'waiting_for_review' || 'rejected') : '' );
```

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Since you're using strings, you will never get `'waiting_for_review'` or `'rejected'` because `'accepted'` is always truthy.

Comment: `!!'string' === true` => your will get `'waiting_for_review'` if `showStateColumn` is truthy. What type of `showStateColumn` ?

Comment: @PetePearl showStateColumn is boolean

Comment: "On this order if they exist"? What order? There's nothing about an order here. Where does the order come from? There's no way to know what *(might | would)* be "better" here.

Comment: @DaveNewton yes, there is an order: in the order those values are in the code and in the order they were also mentioned in the explanation: accepted, waiting for review, rejected ( or empty if StateColumn is not visible = false). These values (accepted, etc), may or not be all present so that's why i cannot pick only one as the default initial value. They are used in a dropdown to filter data. I easily can make it work if i reduce the options to accepted / empty, the problem for me is trying to add 2 more (waiting for review, rejected)

Answer (score 0):

You will need 1 function to be run on every state change of stateColumn. Where will set the state of setSelectedStuffState. But for that also, you will require 1 more state which will decide the optional values of your state.

The logic may work like this

```
const YourComponent = (props) => {
  const { showStateColumn, status } = props;
  const [selectedStuffState, setSelectedStuffState] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    if (showStateColumn) {
      // now here you will require condition to check if the selectedStuffState is 'accepted' || 'waiting_for_review' || 'rejected'
      // you will require 1 more status prop which will decide the state of selectedStuffState

      if (status === "accepted") {
        setSelectedStuffState("");
      } else if (status === "waiting_for_review") {
        setSelectedStuffState("waiting_for_review");
      } else {
        setSelectedStuffState("rejected");
      }
    }
  }, [showStateColumn]); //useEffect will run on every change of showStateColumn
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const setInitalState = () => {
 return showStateColumn? ('accepted' || 'waiting_for_review' || 'rejected') : '' 
}

const [selectedStuffState, setSelectedStuffState] = useState(setInitalState());
```